# 401 error angular routing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have been driving myself crazy. Hoping one of you can help me out here...

Let me give you some background:

I have an ASP.NET web app that uses AngularJS.

Here is what my Controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Ultimately this loads my HomePage and everything comes up great. However when I click a link for example:

```
<a ui-sref="core.applications">My Apps</a>
```

It prompts me to enter in a Username and Password. Even though this should be set for anonymous access.

Now if I open a new tab and go directly to that page for example: http://localhost/#/core/applications this loads just fine.

Looking at my routes:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/core/dashboard');

$stateProvider

    .state('core', {
        url: '/core',
        views: {
            '': { templateUrl: 'app/core/views/core.html' },
            'sidebar@core': {
                templateUrl: 'app/core/views/sidebar.html'
            },
            'content@core': {
                templateUrl: ''
            }
        }
    })
    .state('core.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
            'content@core': {
                templateUrl: 'app/core/views/dashboard.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('core.applications', {
        url: '/applications',
        views: {
            'content@core': {
                templateUrl: 'app/core/views/applications.html'
            }
        }
    })

});
```

I do not see what could be blocking it and prompting it to load a Username and Password. Is it something to do with ASP.NET Routing? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the issue.

The issue was related to the Web API call that I do that I pass security credentials and if the credentials end up being repeated too quickly my system blocks them... (dumb enterprise security guys)

Long story short - check if you are calling a 3rd party service this could prevent you from accessing those pages.